# Does JIT (just in time) run IL (intermediate language) code to machine code line by line or go reads all IL code and then execute machine code

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, interpreter, jit

I'm learning compiler course and I'm confused. My question is about .NET and Java because both of them are using virtual machines (CLR and JVM), and as far as I know for example in C#, a programming language like C# is compiled into IL and passed to the CLR and then the JIT, and here I don't know how the JIT works - line by line, or does it read all IL code and then executes?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: JIT in .NET is usually at the per-method level, unless you are doing AOT compile

Comment: Just in time means exactly that: it only compiles as needed (although inlining can happen also up to a certain depth)